# code EPERM syscall unlink error. BuildError [4294963248]: Build failed with exit code 4294963248

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, tailwind-css, remix

Note that I am using Vscode if it means anything. Now to the issue. My program used to run fine up until recently. I do not remember what happened but for some reason, I am unable to run my app. The issue seems to be related to typescript somehow. Since I get red underlines over most of html code written inside react components.
When I put my cursor over the highlights, I get:

```
JSX element implicitly has type 'any' because no interface 'JSX.IntrinsicElements' exists.ts(7026)
Cannot find module 'react/jsx-runtime' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
```

When I try to run my application, I get  this error in terminal:

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! path C:\Users\app-name\node_modules\@esbuild\win32-x64\esbuild.exe
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\app-name\node_modules\@esbuild\win32-x64\esbuild.exe'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\app-name\node_modules\@esbuild\win32-x64\esbuild.exe'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\app-name\\node_modules\\@esbuild\\win32-x64\\esbuild.exe'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-02-21T02_16_43_812Z-debug-0.log
[mf:err] BuildError [4294963248]: Build failed with exit code 4294963248
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\app-name\node_modules\@miniflare\core\src\plugins\build.ts:77:25)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
BuildError [4294963248]: Build failed with exit code 4294963248
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\app-name\node_modules\@miniflare\core\src\plugins\build.ts:77:25)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
ERROR: "dev:miniflare" exited with 1.
```

package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "sideEffects": false,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "remix build",
    "deploy": "wrangler publish",
    "dev:remix": "remix watch",
    "dev:miniflare": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development miniflare ./build/index.js --watch",
    "dev": "remix build && run-p \"dev:*\"",
    "dev:css": "tailwindcss -i ./styles/tailwind.css -o ./app/styles/tailwind.css -w",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production miniflare ./build/index.js",
    "typecheck": "tsc -b"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@material-tailwind/react": "^1.4.2",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.9",
    "@remix-run/cloudflare": "^1.9.0",
    "@remix-run/cloudflare-workers": "^1.9.0",
    "@remix-run/react": "^1.9.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "remix": "^1.10.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@cloudflare/workers-types": "^3.18.0",
    "@remix-run/dev": "^1.9.0",
    "@remix-run/eslint-config": "^1.9.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@types/styled-components-react-native": "^5.2.1",
    "concurrently": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint": "^8.27.0",
    "miniflare": "^2.11.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4",
    "wrangler": "^2.2.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16.13"
  }
}
```

I have done everything from deleting node_modules folder. to commands like `npm i --save-dev @types/node` to `npm cache clean --force`.
Nothing seems to permanently fix this issue.

Comment: Can you include package.json?

Comment: sure thing. I've attached it now.